# How to show currnt time in seconds and microseconds in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, time

i want to use timespan shows me a current time in this format "SS:FFFFF", any suggestions? what i tried: label1.Text = TimeOfDay.ToString("ss:fffff") - 
Shows only Seconds

Comment: I have a suggestion. Search the web for relevant keywords.  You already know what those keywords are because you have posted them yourself. Do the research, make your best attempt and then, if it doesn't work, post back and show us what you've done and explain what happens and how that differs from your expectations. That's how this site works. We're not here to teach you the basics of VB.NET programming or to save you the effort of a web search.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Wow, take it easy my friend. I know this words because i made it before, i was able to search it to the web. But when i came to the same task over a year, i totally forget the thing. And also cant find it on the web anymore. What i tried so far - label1.Text = TimeOfDay.ToString("ss:fffff"). It shows only seconds

Comment: I am taking it easy. Are you one of these people who think that any sort of criticism is a personal attack? You did the wrong thing, based on the purpose of this site.  I told you what you should do.  If you don't want to be criticised then don't do the wrong thing. If you have tried something and it doesn't work then put that in your question. Every question should contain an explanation of what you want to achieve, how you're trying to achieve it and what happens when you try it. If you don't specify the actual issue then we can waste time on irrelevant or redundant stuff.

Comment: did you check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @Mederic, Thanks,i  found an answer already "Now.ToString(“ss.fffff”)" =)

Comment: @Mederic, the format string is fine. It's the use of `DateAndTime.TimeOfDay` that's the issue, which is a perfect illustration of why it's important that the question includes a full explanation of the current code that isn't working.

Comment: You shouldn't use `Now` either because it is also a VB6 holdover from the `DateAndTime` module.  What you do is up to you but I always recommend not using anything from that `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace that is there basically for backward-compatibility unless it offers some genuine advantage, which it doesn't in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, the issue is that you're using `DateAndTime.TimeOfDay`.  It appears to round the time to the second.  That's basically a holdover from VB6 anyway and this is an example of why you shouldn't use it.  If you use `Date.Now` then the same `ToString` call will do exactly as you want.